# Node.js send JSON to client

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am new to Node.js and javascript. I have a problem which I can't solve. I have a Node application, also I am using Express.

My problem: I have a script that sends a JSON to my server. This data is then stored in my MongoDB.  What i want to do now is display that data on another page. This is what i have:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var dbase = db.db("db");       
    dbase.collection('db').insertOne(req.body, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log('error');
        else
            console.log('success');
            res.render('result');
    });
  });
});
```

What would be the best way to display the data stored in req.body? And could I send it to 'result'? Or should I display the data within the InsertOne-Function?

Answer (score -1):

Please read the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)  for all the details.

The `JSON` response can be sent using `res.json()` method.

Your code will look like this -

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var dbase = db.db("db");       
    dbase.collection('db').insertOne(req.body, function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        console.log('error');
    else
        res.json(result);
    });
  });
});
```